# How should I take a multidimensional array in vuejs?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vuejs2, axios

This problem has made me sleep well in two days.
This is my code with vuejs & axios & nuxt:

```
<template>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="item in data.apilist.interfaces" :key="item" v-if="data.apilist.interfaces">
      {{ item.name }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</template>
<script>
import axios from 'axios'
const util = require('util')
export default {
  data: () => ({
    title: ''
  }),
  async asyncData ({ params, error }) {
    let res = await axios.get(
      `https://bird.ioliu.cn/v1?url=https://api.steampowered.com/ISteamWebAPIUtil/GetSupportedAPIList/v1/`
    )
    return { data: util.inspect(res, { showHidden: true, depth: null }) }
  },
  head () {
    return {
      title: this.title
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Json data : https://api.steampowered.com/ISteamWebAPIUtil/GetSupportedAPIList/v1/

No matter how I do it, I can't get the value of `apilist->interfaces->name`. 
The above example code system prompts me `Cannot read property'interfaces' of undefined` , which part is the problem?

===================update

I have installed `chrome vue dev`, but it seems to work on nuxt applications. Now I try to print the entire data data. 
The data generated when I typed the corresponding connection directly in the browser is as follows: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtjNG.png)

But strange things happen, and when I jump to this link from somewhere else in the application, the data data is like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFQQ0.png)

I tried `v-for="item in data.apilist"` `{{item.interfaces.name}}` or `v-if="data.apilist"` or `v-if="data"` and he no longer complains but no data is generated.

This is the result of the powershell output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIzED.png) && [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWHeD.png)

Comment: Sorry, when I first edited, I pasted the wrong code, the correct code has been updated, still prompting this error

Comment: Did you try to debug your data obejct ? Do you use Chrome Vue Dev tools ? https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd

Comment: I suspect that your statement is incorrect, try : v-if="data.apilist" or v-if="data"

Answer (score 1):

```
Cannot read property'interfaces' of undefined
```

Simply means that you are trying to access to the property "interfaces" on a undefined reference : `somethingThatDoesntExist.interfaces`

Here is the mess :

```
<li v-for="item in data.apilist.interfaces" :key="item" v-if="data.apilist.interfaces">
      {{ data.interfaces }}
    </li>
```

You are iterating on data.apilist.interfaces and binding just beneath :

```
data.interfaces
```

But you need to bind

```
item.interfaces
```

Since you are using `v-for="item in ...`" and not `v-for="data in ..."`.
Code review is important before asking.

Comment: Sorry, I paste in the wrong code, the correct code has been updated, still prompting this error